# How to get margin value with devexpress gridcontrol?

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress

i have a gridcontrol. i really want to learn position of gridcontrol. My another question is where is my mouse cursor. i really want to learn my mouse cursor where is? on gridcontrol? on GridControl scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TableViewHitInfo](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTableViewHitInfotopic) class that allows you to recognize which element is located at the specified screen coordinates via [TableView.CalcHitInfo](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_CalcHitInfotopic) method:

```
void grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    TableViewHitInfo hi =
        ((TableView)grid.View).CalcHitInfo(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
    textBlock.Text = hi.HitTest.ToString();
}
```

Related help article: [Hit Information](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7557)